# REACT Props is undefined in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, function, api, axios, undefined

i'm new with Reactjs and I have a issue with it.

In my parent Component i send a prods id to child Component:

```
<Review id={prod.id}/>
```

I need Product ID to call API in child component

```
export default function Index(props) {
const [pagenum, setPageNum] = useState(0);
const [reviewList, setReviewList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    get(`/public/product/rate?pagenum=${pagenum}&size=4&id=${props.id}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.data);
          setReviewList(response.data);
        }
      });
}, [pagenum]);
return (
    <>
        Hello {props.id}
        {
            reviewList.map((review) => (
                <div>{review.id}</div>
            ))
        }
    </>
);}
```

But the prod.id is return undefined, so I can't call the API. I there any way to send Id to Child Component?

Comment: It should be `<Index id={prod.id}/>` ?  Or add code of `<Review />` component.

Comment: Check your eslint warnings... You missing `props.id` in dep array, I'm sure you are referencing stale values

Comment: No id is not reserved attribute

Comment: do it like this `{prod.id ? <Review id={prod.id}/> : null}`, hope it works

Comment: @DennisVash In my warning it's show:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: @KonstantinModin with part i should add `<Index id={prod.id}/>`

Comment: @LươngQuangHuy you are getting `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` this error because you didnt added `props.id` in the dependency of useEffect, do it like this `[pagenum, props.id]`

Comment: @NishargShah I do it like you said but it still the return of prod.id = undefined

Comment: please console this in the root of the component and check what you get

Comment: @NishargShah it's undefined :(

Comment: console.log, where you are calling this Review Component and check what you get and also check how many times, it is console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `id`  to the dependent array. ([code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-effect-demo-bwsnu))

Updated code sandbox. as per your needs . Please update as per your url and params

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Index(props) {
  const [pagenum, setPageNum] = useState(0);
  const [reviewList, setReviewList] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    //https://api.github.com/users/shawnquinn
    //`/public/product/rate?pagenum=${pagenum}&size=4&id=${props.id}`
    fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/users/shawnquinn?pagenum=${pagenum}&id=${props.id}`
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log("SUccess");
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data);
        setReviewList(response.data || []);
      }
    });
    console.log("Id, ", props.id);
  }, [props.id, pagenum]);

  return ( <
    >
    Hello {
      props.id
    } {
      reviewList.map((review) => ( <
        div > {
          review.id
        } < /div>
      ))
    } <
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    button onClick = {
      () => {
        setId((prev) => prev + 1);
      }
    } >
    Increase Id {
      " "
    } <
    /button> <
    Index id = {
      id
    }
    /> <
    /div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that is not the case because if you pass the id statically there is no way that child can not get it but if you getting it using API you need to check it.

Comment: This work for me. All I need to do is add another useEffect() with [prod.id,pagenum]. Thank you so much!!! It's took me a day and after 10minute in stack, it fixed

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I call API with this way. It's seem like it only run separate with other

Comment: Updated code sandbox. as per your needs . Please update as per your url and params (working code sanbox)